# Parsing DeepDiff result

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, diff

I am working with [DeepDiff](http://deepdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). So I have results like:

```
local =  [{1: {'age': 50, 'name': 'foo'}}, {2: {'age': 90, 'name': 'bar'}}, {3: {'age': 60, 'name': 'foobar'}}]
online = [{1: {'age': 50, 'name': 'foo'}}, {2: {'age': 40, 'name': 'bar'}}]
ddiff = DeepDiff(local, online)
added, updated = ddiff['iterable_item_added'], ddiff['values_changed']
added = {'root[2]': {3: {'age': 60, 'name': 'foobar'}}}
updated = {"root[1][2]['age']": {'new_value': 90, 'old_value': 40}}
```

Now, I want to take:

```
list_indexes_added = foo(added)
list_indexes_updated = foo(updated)
```

and to obtain:

```
list_indexes_added = [2]
list_index_updated = [(1,2,'age')]
```

in this way, I can manipulate the list `local` and `online` and in the future update the `online` table.

I am thinking in regexs, but maybe there is other option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- One solution can be regex and custom parsing of the matches.
- Another can be using `literal_eval` after regex parsing on these strings, if the output format of `deepdiff` is consistent

  ```
  from ast import literal_eval
  import re


  def str_diff_parse(str_diff):
      return [tuple(literal_eval(y) for y in re.findall(r"\[('?\w+'?)\]", x)) for x in str_diff]

  added = {'root[2]': {3: {'age': 60, 'name': 'foobar'}}}
  updated = {"root[1][2]['age']": {'new_value': 90, 'old_value': 40}}

  list_indexes_added = str_diff_parse(added)
  list_indexes_updated = str_diff_parse(updated)

  print(list_indexes_added)
  print(list_indexes_updated)
  # prints
  #[(2,)]
  #[(1, 2, 'age')]
  ```

**demo** : http://ideone.com/3MhTky

- Would also recommend [dictdiffer](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/dictdiffer) module, it returns the diff as a consumable python diff object which can be patched to original dictionary to get the updated one or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

So, I'd go with something like this:

```
import re

def foo(diff):
modded = []

for key in diff.keys():
    m = re.search('\[(.+)\]', key)
    modded.append(tuple(m.group(1).split('][')))

return modded
```

It'll read each key, extract only the indices (whether numeric or string), then slice up the string. Since your desired output indicates a tuple, it'll spit the sequence of indices back as one, then return the whole list of index sets (since `diff` might have more than one).

This can be golfed down into a one-line list comprehension:

```
import re

def foo(diff):
    return [tuple(re.search('\[(.+)\]', key).group(1).split('][')) for key in diff.keys()]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did:

```
def getFromSquareBrackets(s):
    return re.findall(r"\['?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)'?\]", s)

def auxparse(e):
    try:
        e = int(e)
    except:
        pass
    return e

def castInts(l):
    return list((map(auxparse, l)))

def parseRoots(dics):
    """
        Returns pos id for list.
        Because we have formmatted [{id:{dic}}, {id:{dic}}]
    """
    values = []
    for d in dics:
        values.append(castInts(getFromSquareBrackets(d)))
    return values
```

So:

```
parseRoots({"root[1][2]['age']": {'new_value': 90, 'old_value': 40}})
[[1, 2, 'age']]
```

Maybe someone can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Author of DeepDiff here.
Please use `parse_path` as noted in the [F.A.Q](https://zepworks.com/deepdiff/current/faq.html#q-how-do-i-parse-deepdiff-result-paths)

```
>>> from deepdiff import parse_path
>>> parse_path("root[1][2]['age']")
[1, 2, 'age']
>>> parse_path("root[1][2]['age']", include_actions=True)
[{'element': 1, 'action': 'GET'}, {'element': 2, 'action': 'GET'}, {'element': 'age', 'action': 'GET'}]
>>>
>>> parse_path("root['joe'].age")
['joe', 'age']
>>> parse_path("root['joe'].age", include_actions=True)
[{'element': 'joe', 'action': 'GET'}, {'element': 'age', 'action': 'GETATTR'}]
```